# Add custom headers to Next.js responses based on environment

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to add the the [X-Robots-Tag header](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag#xrobotstag) to all Next.js HTTP responses based on *something* in the environment the server is deployed to -- whether that is an environment variable (my preference) or anything else.

My Next.js application is deployed to two environments: an integration testing environment that uses the production Next.js build (`NODE_ENV="production"`) but is connected to non-prod services, and the actual production environment that serves user traffic. I want to add the header only to the integration testing environment.

I've tried adding the header conditionally based on `process.env.INTEGRATION`*`TEST`*`ENV` in [`headers()` in next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers), but any env var like `process.env.XYZ` seems to be evaluated at build time, not at runtime. For example, this doesn't work, even though the `INTEGRATION_TEST_ENV` environment variable is set to the string "true" on the server:

```
headers() {
      if (process.env.INTEGRATION_TEST_ENV === "true") {
        console.log("This code will never be run. The condition never evaluates to true, despite the runtime env var actually being set to 'true'.")
        return [
          {
            source: "/:path*",
            headers: [
              {
                key: "X-Robots-Tag",
                value: "none",
              },
            ],
          },
        ]
      }
    },
```

I can't use next.config.js's phases either, since both my integration test and "real production" are running the production build and production server.

A [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) might solve the problem, but it seems like overkill, especially with the loss of automatic static optimization.

Is there any way to add a header based on a runtime environment variable?

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to conditionally call `context.res.setHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "none")` via [getServerSideProps(context)](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter). You could just return empty props (`props: {}`) or omit them from the page's default component's signature (`export default function SomePage()`). However, like the custom server approach, you'd also lose automatic static optimization since the page would need to be generated at request time.

Comment: @MarkG Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. I was hoping somebody had a better solution. Feel free to leave an answer and I'll accept it if there is indeed no way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-`getServerSideProps(context)` option would be to use a [`_middleware` page](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware):

```js
// pages/_middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware() {
  const res = NextResponse.next();

  // `process.env` evaluated at build time
  if (process.env.INTEGRATION_TEST_ENV === "true") {
    res.headers.set("X-Robots-Tag", "none");
  }

  return res;
}
```

I'm not sure if you're just compiling once then each deployment target gets the same bundle (and so the environment variable would be "baked-in"), but if you can find a workaround for that, this could potentially work.

And the other approach [mentioned in the comments earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722818/add-custom-headers-to-next-js-responses-based-on-environment#comment126762915_71722818):

```js
export default function Home() {
  return "Hello, world!";
}

// automatic static optimization no longer applies 
export function getServerSideProps(context) {
  if (process.env.INTEGRATION_TEST_ENV === "true") {
    context.res.setHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "none");
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

Comment: The middleware option is precisely what I was looking for. It has access to deployment-time environment variables, but doesn't interfere with automatic static optimization. Thank you!